# reproject lon/lat in wgs84 to target projection using tilestache/modestmaps?

Tags: python, tilestache

The documentation for tilestache is a little sparse.  Is there a way to transform a point (lon/lat) in wgs84 to a target projection?

Where:

```
target_srid = 3095
target_proj4_str = '+proj=utm +zone=54 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=-146.414,507.337,680.507,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs'
```

I've noticed that there is a tranform object in ModestMaps at:

```
ModestMaps.Geo.Transform()
```

But I'm not clear on how it can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is the Proj4Projection class under “Goodies”:

http://tilestache.org/doc/TileStache.Goodies.Proj4Projection.html

I’m currently only including WGS84 and Spherical Mercator in the core of TileStache, but the contributed module above should help you. Be aware that you need to figure out a transformation in addition to a projection, explained in this excellent guide from Per Liedman: http://blog.kartena.se/local-projections-in-a-world-of-spherical-mercator/

Comment: Tried, but I can't seem to load Proj4Projection.  >>> proj = TileStache.Goodies.Proj4Projection()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Proj4Projection'

Comment: ended up just reprojecting the data into 900913, much easier to handle then.

Answer (score 1):

Proj4Projection has a dependency (pyproj). I'm not sure what specifically you're trying to do, but if you're trying to make data compatible with what TileStache is expecting, I would just use `ST_Transform` in the actual SQL queries to have PostGIS project to 4326. It's not the cleanest way to do it, but it would at least prevent data redundancy.

Also see this: http://vis4.net/blog/posts/no-more-mercator-tiles/